# Installing websphere application server 7 in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, websphere-7

I have followed the instructions given in this link http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/538 to install websphere 7 in eclipse juno.Everything went smoothly but when I tried to define the websphere installation directory, it is not accepting the location that I am specifying.I am sure the installation of the server is working fine as I was able to deploy an ear from admin console.The installation path that I am specifying is this 
**C:\Users\User1\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer**
I have added the following in the eclipse configuration file
**-vm 
C:\Users\User1\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\javaw.exe**

Comment: I followed the same instructions and it worked for me :) In my case the path is `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer`

Comment: thanks for this post. It helped me find a free soln to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong path.

Try reference this path bellow:

C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer